# Is it possible to automate tests for a peer to peer network with virtualbox?

Tags: networking, scripting, virtualbox

I'm writing a C peer to peer application and at the moment I'm testing it with VirtualBox. Every time, I startup several virtual machines and try different commands in different machines to see how the whole network works. **Is there a way to automate this testing procedure**? It's really boring having to accomplish all times the same tasks (turn on virtual machines, start a bootserver program on a machine, peer programs on other machines, test requesting a file from a single peer manually... and so on).

Comment: I'm not sure, should I post this question on stackoverflow instead?

Comment: You will be able to automate your tests using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), plus the syntax is very easy, you should be able to learn the basics within a day.

Comment: You can make it significantly faster by using network namespaces instead of virtualbox. A few self-made scripts should be sufficient, but there are [ready-made applications](http://www.brianlinkletter.com/open-source-network-simulators/).

Comment: @Robb1 I don't think that StackOverflow is a more appropriate forum than unix.stackexchange.com. The most appropriate site would probably devops.stackexchange.com, but that's still in beta.

Comment: If you can list the commands you use, we might have a chance of helping.

Comment: [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this sort of task falls under the broader category of [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps). A more specific keyword (buzzword?) that you might be looking for is [orchestration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestration_(computing)). There are more tools for this sort of thing than any one person could possibly want to know about. Check out the [list of orchestration tools](http://www.devopsbookmarks.com/orchestration) on [DevOps Bookmarks](http://www.devopsbookmarks.com/) for some possibilities.

That said, you can probably do what you want with nothing more than a little shell scripting. You can use the [vboxmanage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) command to automate the booting and shutting down of your VMs. You can then use either SSH or a [virtual serial port](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#serialports) to kick off jobs on each of the VMs and gather the results.

It also might be worth thinking about whether or not you really need full virtualization. If you're working on Linux then you might consider using Linux Containers with Docker. Docker has an orchestration tool called [Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) which was developed to coordinate multi-container applications and which would probably work well for your use case.

I might be able to say more if you gave more details about exactly what you're trying to do.